# Easiest/cheapest from Albuquerque Amtrak to car rental at airport

Tags: usa, airport-transfer, amtrak

I am planning to arrive in Albuquerque, NM via an Amtrak train. I want to rent a car when I arrive, which will most likely require a trip to the airport (where I will be leaving the car anyway).

I know that if you rent with Hertz they will refund your taxi ride from the Amtrak station to the airport. But I have not yet seen the equivalent for any other rental companies (and as I will probably book the car with a site like Hotwire, I have no idea who I will end up renting with beforehand<sup>1</sup>).

So what would be the easiest/cheapest solution to get from the Amtrak station to the airport for two people (with at least one large suitcase)?

---

<sup>1</sup> I am aware that if I end up with Enterprise that nominally they will pick you up from the station.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was in Albuquerque this last week.  The City Bus terminal is next door to the Amtrak station.  From there you can take a number 50 bus to the airport for $1 per person (and they take $1 bills inside the bus - not sure about coins).  This is a local bus and takes about 1/2 hour to get to the airport and runs many times per day.  This is the bus that I took.

Alternatively there is the number 250 bus which is an express direct to the airport and is advertised as being free.  This bus doesn't run as often as the 50 bus, and its schedule didn't match up with my needs - which is why I took the 50 bus.

See [City of Albuquerque Bus Routes & Schedules](https://www.cabq.gov/transit/bus-routes-and-schedules) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use any search engine, Expeia, Kayak, etc. to search for cars at the zip code of the Amtrak Station.

Many agencies have off-airport locations.  This is frequently better because you save airport taxes and fees.

Then determine the best way to get there.  All things being equal, I would use Uber.